# How to add additional summarized and calculated columns with jq for JSON

Tags: json, shell, jq

```
curl -s "https://api.test-foo.com" \ |  jq -r '  .[] | .[:5]  | .[0] |= (./1000 | strflocaltime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"))  | .[1,2,3,4] |= tonumber  | .[5] = (.[2] + .[3]) / 2  |  .[6] =  ( (.[2] - .[5]) / .[5] + (.[3] - .[5]) / .[5] * -1 ) * 100 | @csv ' > JSON.csv;
```

This jq code exports the result like below (48 lines for every hour)

```
2022/06/24 02:00:00 5.94    6.09    5.91    6.06    6   3.0000000000000000
2022/06/24 03:00:00 6.06    6.07    5.98    6.02    6.025   1.4937759336099600
2022/06/24 04:00:00 6.02    6.26    5.99    6.24    6.125   4.408163265306120
2022/06/24 05:00:00 6.23    6.32    6.18    6.19    6.25    2.240000000000010
2022/06/24 06:00:00 6.19    6.26    6.13    6.26    6.195   2.0984665052461600
2022/06/24 07:00:00 6.26    6.44    6.26    6.3 6.35    2.834645669291350
2022/06/24 08:00:00 6.3 6.4 6.28    6.31    6.34    1.89274447949527
2022/06/24 09:00:00 6.32    6.4 6.18    6.25    6.29    3.4976152623211500
2022/06/24 10:00:00 6.24    6.39    6.22    6.29    6.305   2.696272799365580
2022/06/24 11:00:00 6.29    6.48    6.24    6.34    6.36    3.7735849056603800
2022/06/24 12:00:00 6.34    6.41    6.27    6.29    6.34    2.208201892744490
2022/06/24 13:00:00 6.29    6.35    6.22    6.27    6.285   2.068416865552900
2022/06/24 14:00:00 6.28    6.39    6.25    6.29    6.32    2.2151898734177200
2022/06/24 15:00:00 6.29    6.69    6.23    6.47    6.460000000000000   7.120743034055730
2022/06/24 16:00:00 6.48    6.51    6.25    6.34    6.38    4.075235109717870
2022/06/24 17:00:00 6.34    6.46    6.32    6.4 6.390000000000000   2.190923317683880
2022/06/24 18:00:00 6.4 6.43    6.32    6.36    6.375   1.7254901960784200
2022/06/24 19:00:00 6.36    6.37    6.29    6.37    6.33    1.263823064770930
2022/06/24 20:00:00 6.37    6.48    6.35    6.41    6.415   2.0265003897116300
2022/06/24 21:00:00 6.41    6.5 6.36    6.41    6.43    2.177293934681180
2022/06/24 22:00:00 6.41    6.46    6.38    6.38    6.42    1.2461059190031200
2022/06/24 23:00:00 6.39    6.46    6.31    6.33    6.385   2.349256068911520
2022/06/25 00:00:00 6.33    6.34    6.25    6.32    6.295   1.4297061159650500
2022/06/25 01:00:00 6.31    6.34    6.21    6.33    6.275   2.0717131474103600
2022/06/25 02:00:00 6.33    6.39    6.3 6.32    6.345   1.4184397163120500
2022/06/25 03:00:00 6.31    6.37    6.29    6.36    6.33    1.263823064770930
2022/06/25 04:00:00 6.36    6.43    6.33    6.41    6.38    1.5673981191222500
2022/06/25 05:00:00 6.42    6.47    6.39    6.41    6.43    1.2441679626749600
2022/06/25 06:00:00 6.41    6.58    6.39    6.49    6.485000000000000   2.9298380878951500
2022/06/25 07:00:00 6.48    6.59    6.47    6.48    6.530000000000000   1.8376722817764200
2022/06/25 08:00:00 6.48    6.58    6.45    6.58    6.515000000000000   1.9953952417498100
2022/06/25 09:00:00 6.58    6.8 6.39    6.41    6.595   6.216830932524640
2022/06/25 10:00:00 6.41    6.54    6.37    6.49    6.455   2.6336173508907800
2022/06/25 11:00:00 6.49    6.49    6.37    6.41    6.43    1.8662519440124400
2022/06/25 12:00:00 6.4 6.49    6.4 6.46    6.445   1.3964313421256800
2022/06/25 13:00:00 6.46    6.49    6.41    6.45    6.45    1.240310077519380
2022/06/25 14:00:00 6.46    6.69    6.43    6.54    6.5600000000000000  3.963414634146350
2022/06/25 15:00:00 6.54    6.55    6.46    6.51    6.505   1.3835511145272800
2022/06/25 16:00:00 6.51    6.61    6.51    6.58    6.5600000000000000  1.524390243902450
2022/06/25 17:00:00 6.57    6.61    6.5 6.51    6.555   1.6781083142639300
2022/06/25 18:00:00 6.52    6.57    6.49    6.55    6.53    1.225114854517610
2022/06/25 19:00:00 6.54    6.59    6.5 6.53    6.545   1.3750954927425500
2022/06/25 20:00:00 6.53    6.56    6.41    6.44    6.485000000000000   2.3130300693908900
2022/06/25 21:00:00 6.44    6.48    6.23    6.3 6.355   3.9339103068450000
2022/06/25 22:00:00 6.29    6.37    6.26    6.31    6.3150000000000000  1.741884402216950
2022/06/25 23:00:00 6.31    6.35    6.26    6.3 6.305   1.4274385408406000
2022/06/26 00:00:00 6.29    6.33    6.14    6.17    6.235000000000000   3.0473135525260700
2022/06/26 01:00:00 6.17    6.24    6.14    6.24    6.1900000000000000  1.6155088852988800
```

Now, I want those additional columns below in the end of columns

1. Average of 7th column (Among all 48 rows. It should be -> 2.35297)
2. Average of 7th column (Among first 12 hours(1-12 rows) only. It should be -> 2.68432)
3. Average of 7th column (Among next 12 hours(13-24 rows) only. It should be -> 2.49099)
4. Average of 7th column (Among next 12 hours(25-36 rows) only. It should be -> 2.13418)
5. Average of 7th column (Among next 12 hours(37-48 rows) only. It should be -> 2.10239)
6. The fixed string "FLAG" for all 48 rows

Of course, it doesn't matter even if all the same numbers are comes in those columns among all 48 records.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: what have you tried at all ????

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the best tool for you is "awk".

The point 1 could be (remember that date and hour are two separate columns):

```
YOUR-COMMAND | awk '
BEGIN { S=.0; C=.0; }
{ S += $8; C += 1; }
END { print S/C; }
'
```